# Orientation lock for iPhone only

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, screen-orientation, uiscreen

I have designed `UI` for my `iOS` app with `wAny hRegular` setting.

Now `orientation` works fine in `iPad`. But when app is running on `iPhone`, `orientation` gives a blank white screen.

Is there any way such that I can lock `orientation` in `iPhones` only and orientation is available for `iPad`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientation` `UIViewController` methods to lock the rotation on iPhone but not on iPad.

Simply return `YES` for iPad and `NO` for iPhone in `shouldAutorotate`, and you returns the allowed orientation for iPhone/iPad in `supportedInterfaceOrientation`.

Answer (score 0):

*Yes @david"mArm"Ansermot is right, I have just added the code, for quick snap:-*

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
         UIDevice* thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
        if(thisDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
          {
             return YES;
          }
        return NO;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    UIDevice* thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if(thisDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
          {
            return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
           }
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply Vizllx but still while rotating simulator blank screen appears :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from project settings, please find the screenshots

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln1ZE.png "iPhone settings"

2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Dsq.png  "iPad settings"